# Sum Distinct Join with where condition

Tags: mysql, join, sum, distinct

I'm a bit stuck. This problem was close to what I need but not quite:

[Products_Final] is a Joined table with Order Table on order id

Order Table is

```
Order ID|Order Date
=====================
    1       1.1.19
    2       1.20.19
```

so on and so forth

```
ProductFINAL_ID | fruit | Country | Quantity |Order Date
=================================================
    1         Apple         USA           100  1.1.19
    2         Apple         USA         100 1.1.19
    3         Apple          Italy          10 1.21.19
    4         Apple         Japan          30  1.22.19
    5         Apple          USA        100    2.1.19
```

So if I do

```
Select Fruit, Country,  sum(qty)
from Products  p
join order o on o.order_id = p.order-id
where Order_date < 2.1.19
group by fruit, country


Fruit|Country|Quantity
==========================
    Apple USA 200
    Apple Italy 10
    Apple Japan 30
```

What I want is the total of `100+10+30 = 140` based on a distinct fruit and country combo since it looks like Product_id 2 might be a duplicate order.

```
Quantity
140
```

If I do distinct, the sum doesn't seem to work.

How do I combine the two things together? I also tried the below but then the join doesn't work

```
Select sum(qty)
from (select distinct (fruit,country), qty from Products)
join order o on o.order_id = p.order-id <- this part errors out
where Order_date < 2.1.19
```

Comment: Is the second table you showed the `Products` table? Where is the `order_id` column?

Comment: Should `p.order-id` be `p.ProductFinal_ID`?

Comment: I don't see how you're getting that result. The `Order` table only has order ID 1 and 2, how are rows 3-5 getting into the result?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it doesn't apply to specific columns, it applies to the entire `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Fruit, Country, SUM(qty)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT order_id, fruit, country, qty FROM products) AS p
JOIN orders AS o ON o.order_id = p.order_id
WHERE Order_date < 2.1.19
GROUP BY fruit, country
```

You need to select `order_id` in the subquery so you can join with it. Don't put parentheses around any of the columns in the `SELECT` list.